# including a WCF service project in my website solution and referencing it

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Im new to .net and I have my website solution and I added my database WCF service to the solution, how can i reference the service's interfaces? I will be making changes to the service as i develop, do I have to build/Deploy the service every time or can i just reference the .svc file somehow?

Comment: If your WCF service is a separate project in the same solution as your web project then you should be able to follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) under the "To add a reference to a service in the current solution" heading...After you make changes you can just use the instructions under "Update a Service Reference" to make sure your web project is in sync with the service changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nkvu - moving out of the comments & as an answer in case it needs to be found later...]

If your WCF service is a separate project in the same solution as your web project then you should be able to follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) under the "To add a reference to a service in the current solution" heading...After you make changes you can just use the instructions under "Update a Service Reference" to make sure your web project is in sync with the service changes